# Materialize.toast show a toast only once

Tags: materialize

Does anyone know of a way to show a toast only once? Right now let's say if you keep clicking on a button to display a toast, they will just keep stacking on top of each other before the previous one has expired. Kind of annoying. Is there any way?

Comment: you can make click disable untill there is toast  and then enable

Comment: thanks but it is not onclick. it was a function that is running. I was just giving an example.

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to achieve this.

The first that comes to mind is the following. let's say you have a function that triggers your toast. Once the toast is triggered, set a global flag (something like `toastCurrentlyDisplayed = true`) and prevent that function from opening the toast again if the flag is set to true. I.e.:

```
myFunction() {
  if (!toastCurrentlyDisplayed) {
    //Logic to open your toast here
  }
}
```

Then simply use a callback to reset the flag once the toast has been dismissed, like

`<a class="btn" onclick="M.toast({html: 'I am a toast', completeCallback: function(){alert('Your toast was dismissed')}})">Toast!</a>`

Answer (score 1):

You can hide toast on click and then use condition for toast. Like

```
$("btn").click(function(e){
    $('.toast').hide();
    if(//some condn){
        Materialize.toast("Enter Your Text here",1500);

    }
});
```

This will hide all toast and show toast only once after clicking many times too.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best method will be to dismiss all the toasts before creating a new Toast, it worked for me.

```
M.Toast.dismissAll();
           const toastHTML = `<span>${data.error}</span><button onClick='M.Toast.getInstance(this.parentElement).dismiss();' class="btn-flat toast-action"><i class="medium material-icons">clear</i></button>`;
            M.toast({html:toastHTML,classes:"#c62828 red darken-3 rounded"})
```

An ideal Toast with a close button and will only show once